# how to use google Data Prep for several files located in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: csv, text-files, google-cloud-dataprep

I imported a text file from in GCS and did some preparations using DataPrep and write them back to GCS as CSV files. What I want to do is, **do this for all the text files in that bucket** Is there a way to do this for all the files in that bucket(in GCS) at once?

Below is my procedure. I selected a textfile from GCS(can't select more than one text file) and did some preparations(rename columns .create new columns and etc). Then write it back to GCS as CSV.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Dataset with parameters** feature to load several files at once.

You can then use a wildcard to select all the files that you want to load.
Note that all the files need to have the same schema (same columns) for this to work.

[image: create dataset with parameters]

See https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Create-Dataset-with-Parameters_118228628 for more information on how to use this feature.

An other solution is to add all the files into a folder* and to use the large **+** button to load all the files in that folder.

[*] technically under the same prefix on GCS